# If the field was essentially changed, then change the value of one of its column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have the essence of the "Requirements". If the user has changed the field "Description" in this instance, it should automatically change the value of the field "Stability" (dropdownlist). That is, if you had to change the description of the requirements, it becomes unstable. I wrote a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeStabilityRequirement]
ON [dbo].[Requirement] AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    if update([Definition])
    begin
        update [Requirement] set Stability = 2 
        where RequirementId in (select RequirementId from inserted)
    end
end
```

But the problem is that the trigger is activated when any change entries in the table. A need to respond only to changes in the column "Definition".

**MY TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Requirement] (
    [RequirementId]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Rationale]                       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [CreatedOn]                       DATE           CONSTRAINT [DF__Requireme__Creat__473C8FC7] DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
    [CurentVersion]                   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [State]                           INT            NOT NULL,
    [Priority]                        INT            NOT NULL,
    [Type]                            INT            NOT NULL,
    [Source_BusinessRuleId]           INT            NULL,
    [Stability]                       INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserPart]                        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [CreatedBy_UserId]                INT            NULL,
    [Responsible_UserId]              INT            NULL,
    [ImplementationVersion]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ResponsibleId]                   INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [SourceId]                        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [InterfacePoint_InterfacePointId] INT            NULL,
    [InterfacePointId]                INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [CreatedById]                     INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [Definition]                      NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Requirement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RequirementId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Requirement_dbo.User_CreatedById] FOREIGN KEY ([CreatedById]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Requirement_dbo.User_ResponsibleId] FOREIGN KEY ([ResponsibleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Requirement_dbo.BusinessRule_SourceId] FOREIGN KEY ([SourceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BusinessRule] ([BusinessRuleId])
);
```

**Update table**
Updating occurs in a web application interface

**This is query from SQL SERVER Profile**

```
exec [dbo].[Requirement_Update] 
@RequirementId=32,
@Definition=N'Реализовать возможность выбора значения "Без пени" в поле "Тип начисления пени". Диалоговое окно АР-12',
@Rationale=N'В соответствии с изменением бизнес-правила',
@CreatedOn='2014-12-18 00:00:00',
@CurentVersion=N'2.1',
@ImplementationVersion=N'2.2',
@State=0,
@Priority=1,
@Stability=1,
@Type=0
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you use? Sql Server?

Comment: In SQL Server i can not reproduce your situation. Besides in your trigger you are updating entire table.

Comment: Your query has a major problem `update [Requirement] set Stability = 2` this line will update all the data in the table not only the updated rows

Comment: How can I update a table column that was not updated the entire table?

Comment: Instead you should use this sentense `update [Requirement] set Stability = 2 where id in (select id from inserted)` (supposing your table has id field)

Comment: I corrected the trigger, as you wrote, but he still works when you change any column

Comment: As I've said I can not reproduce this behavior. Can you paste some simple   Create table and Trigger statements and also some update statements to reproduce this?

Comment: Can you profile the `Update query` and edit your question?

Comment: I am suspicious that your `Update query` contains `Definition`

Comment: I can not. Updating occurs in a web application interface

Comment: May be, but i dont know where i can take this query

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler to catch query. Are you sure there are no other triggers on that table?

Comment: There are no other triggers, I am sure. RezaRahmati was right :(

Comment: Update request does contain all the columns including "Definition". How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you need update Requirement only when Definition is updated then change your trigger as:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeStabilityRequirement]
    ON [dbo].[Requirement] AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        if update([Definition]) AND NOT update([Rationale]) AND NOT update([CurentVersion]) 
         --AND NOT UPDATE(.....list here all possible columns that may be updated 
        begin
            update [Requirement] set Stability = 2 
            where RequirementId in (select RequirementId from inserted)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Now "Stability" never set = 2

Comment: Now you should decide whether update Stability only when Definition is changed or when Definition is changed with any other column.
Obviously Stability is not changed because you have got no update query which updates only Definition column.

Comment: when Definition is changed with any other column :)

Comment: Then IF UPDATE(Definition) is enough. It means If(Definition is changed or Definition and other columns changed)

Comment: Then why the trigger fires when I do not change the field "Definition", and modify any other field?

Comment: Because triggers are set on tables not on columns. You can not set trigger on particular column update. If any column is updated you trigger will fire.